# Facebook Attribution tracking template in Google Ads

Tags: facebook, google-ads-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to setup Google Ads Click Tag tracking for Facebook Attribution and I have some difficulties to finish it.

I copied the Click Tag from[enter image description here: 
[image]

But when I paste it to Google Ads Tracking Settings and I test it I see this "Final URL Mismatch" error:
[image]

Is there anything wrong with tracking template? Or is it okay to save it and ignore the error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider that [cross-domain redirects are not allowed](https://instapage.com/blog/adwords-final-url) in case of Google Ads? I think it's not meant to use it with Google Ads.

So my take is that if you use the Final URL for situations when parallel tracking is not allowed, it should work.